# Magento 2 how to add email in billing address form?

Tags: magento2, billing-address

Magento 2 how to add email in billing address form?
[image]

Comment: May this MagePlaza Document will help you. https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-new-fields-address-form-magento-2.html. Or I will share one code spinnet, that will help you

Answer (score 0):

we need to create a plugin for the \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor::process method.

so for create the plugin first we should make an entry in di.xml.

Path: `app/code/OSCP/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="add_custom_field_checkout_form" type="OSCP\ModuleName\Model\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create plugin class on this Directory. Path: `app\code\OSCP\ModuleName\Model\Plugin\Checkout`

```
namespace OSCP\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout;
class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $configuration = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];
        foreach ($configuration as $paymentGroup => $groupConfig) {
            if (isset($groupConfig['component']) AND $groupConfig['component'] === 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address') {

                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentGroup]['children']['form-fields']['children']['company_tax_id'] = [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'billingAddress.custom_attributes',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                        'options' => [],
                        'id' => 'custom-field'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => 'billingAddress.custom_attributes.custom_field',
                    'label' => 'Email',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'validation' => [],
                    'sortOrder' => 250,
                    'id' => 'custom-field'
                ];
            }
        }


        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```